# Is there a reason for the seemingly random twenty bytes at location 0x284 in the compiled code from gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

The following code illustrates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_1 1

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    a = NUMBER_1;
    printf("Output: %d\r\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Changing the `define` to 2 causes the 20 bytes to change completely. I'm using gcc version 7.5.0 under Ubuntu version 18.04. I suspect this is some sort of digest but if so why is it there and when is it checked. Editing these bytes with a hex editor does not keep the code from executing.

Output from `readelf -a`:

```
ELF Header:

  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x540
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6448 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28

Section Headers:

  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000000238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000000254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             0000000000000274  00000274
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000000298  00000298
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000000002b8  000002b8
       00000000000000a8  0000000000000018   A       6     1     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000360  00000360
       0000000000000084  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           00000000000003e4  000003e4
       000000000000000e  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          00000000000003f8  000003f8
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       6     1     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000418  00000418
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             00000000000004d8  000004d8
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018  AI       5    22     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         00000000000004f0  000004f0
       0000000000000017  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000000510  00000510
       0000000000000020  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS         0000000000000530  00000530
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  AX       0     0     8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000540  00000540
       00000000000001b2  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000000006f4  000006f4
       0000000000000009  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000000700  00000700
       0000000000000011  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000000714  00000714
       000000000000003c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000750  00000750
       0000000000000108  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       0000000000200db8  00000db8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000000200dc0  00000dc0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000200dc8  00000dc8
       00000000000001f0  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000200fb8  00000fb8
       0000000000000048  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000201000  00001000
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000201010  00001010
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [25] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001010
       0000000000000029  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00001040
       00000000000005e8  0000000000000018          27    43     8
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001628
       0000000000000205  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  0000182d
       00000000000000fe  0000000000000000           0     0     1

Key to Flags:

  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  l (large), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:

  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000858 0x0000000000000858  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000db8 0x0000000000200db8 0x0000000000200db8
                 0x0000000000000258 0x0000000000000260  RW     0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000dc8 0x0000000000200dc8 0x0000000000200dc8
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000714 0x0000000000000714 0x0000000000000714
                 0x000000000000003c 0x000000000000003c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000db8 0x0000000000200db8 0x0000000000200db8
                 0x0000000000000248 0x0000000000000248  R      0x1

Section to Segment mapping:

  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym   .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt   .plt.got .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .data .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
   08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got

Dynamic section at offset 0xdc8 contains 27 entries:

  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x4f0
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x6f4
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x200db8
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x200dc0
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x298
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x360
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x2b8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              132 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x200fb8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x4d8
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x418
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             192 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x3f8
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x3e4
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x418 contains 8 entries:

  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name +     Addend
000000200db8  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    640
000000200dc0  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    600
000000201008  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    201008
000000200fd8  000100000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000   _ITM_deregisterTMClone + 0
000000200fe0  000300000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000200fe8  000400000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000200ff0  000500000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTa + 0
000000200ff8  000600000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x4d8 contains 1 entry:

  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name +   Addend
000000200fd0  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000   printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type Advanced Micro Devices X86-64 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 7 entries:

   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     5: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 63 entries:

   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000238     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000254     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000274     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000298     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     5: 00000000000002b8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     6: 0000000000000360     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     7: 00000000000003e4     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
     8: 00000000000003f8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8
     9: 0000000000000418     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
    10: 00000000000004d8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10
    11: 00000000000004f0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11
    12: 0000000000000510     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12
    13: 0000000000000530     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13
    14: 0000000000000540     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14
    15: 00000000000006f4     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15
    16: 0000000000000700     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16
    17: 0000000000000714     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17
    18: 0000000000000750     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18
    19: 0000000000200db8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19
    20: 0000000000200dc0     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20
    21: 0000000000200dc8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21
    22: 0000000000200fb8     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22
    23: 0000000000201000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23
    24: 0000000000201010     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24
    25: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25
    26: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    27: 0000000000000570     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 deregister_tm_clones
    28: 00000000000005b0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 register_tm_clones
    29: 0000000000000600     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 __do_global_dtors_aux
    30: 0000000000201010     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 completed.7698
    31: 0000000000200dc0     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20   __do_global_dtors_aux_fin
    32: 0000000000000640     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 frame_dummy
    33: 0000000000200db8     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 __frame_dummy_init_array_
    34: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS study.c
    35: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    36: 0000000000000854     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   18 __FRAME_END__
    37: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
    38: 0000000000200dc0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 __init_array_end
    39: 0000000000200dc8     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 _DYNAMIC
    40: 0000000000200db8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   19 __init_array_start
    41: 0000000000000714     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
    42: 0000000000200fb8     0 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   22 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    43: 00000000000006f0     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 __libc_csu_fini
    44: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
    45: 0000000000201000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT   23 data_start
    46: 0000000000201010     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 _edata
    47: 00000000000006f4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _fini
    48: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
    49: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND   __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    50: 0000000000201000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __data_start
    51: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    52: 0000000000201008     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    23 __dso_handle
    53: 0000000000000700     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 _IO_stdin_used
    54: 0000000000000680   101 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 __libc_csu_init
    55: 0000000000201018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _end
    56: 0000000000000540    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _start
    57: 0000000000201010     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 __bss_start
    58: 000000000000064a    44 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
    59: 0000000000201010     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    23 __TMC_END__
    60: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND   _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
    61: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2
    62: 00000000000004f0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _init

Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 7 entries:

 Addr: 00000000000003e4  Offset: 0x0003e4  Link: 5 (.dynsym)
  000:   0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       2 (GLIBC_2.2.5)   2 (GLIBC_2.2.5)
  004:   0 (*local*)       0 (*local*)       2 (GLIBC_2.2.5)

Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 1 entry:

 Addr: 0x00000000000003f8  Offset: 0x0003f8  Link: 6 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 1
  0x0010:   Name: GLIBC_2.2.5  Flags: none  Version: 2

Displaying notes found in: .note.ABI-tag

  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 3.2.0

Displaying notes found in: .note.gnu.build-id

  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: c095e6656212ec526608978b52cbe1108b59d0ef
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the _complete and unedited_ output of `readelf -a a.out` (replacing `a.out` with the actual name of your compiled program).

Comment: It would also help to know what compilation flags you used.

Comment: compiled with "gcc -o study study.c"

Comment: The output of "readelf -a study" is apparently too long to post as a comment. Is there a particular part that might help?

Comment: Unfortunately, knowing only what you've told us, I really do need to see all of the output. This is why I said to provide the info by editing your question. (Did you know you can edit your question? The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button. Yes, it's bad UI design. Sorry about that.)

Comment: Is it a timestamp?

Comment: does not appear to be a timestamp as it does not change upon recompiling at a different time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a diff of the output of `readelf -a`, you'll see that there is a change in the "Build ID" field:

```
269c269
<     Build ID: 5cee13af3549a15ae34a9a55fd49ec5e7d1f91ea
---
>     Build ID: 0a2669d15ff23ae536f7496c1e0aa57051d29111
```

---

If you do a diff on the hex data of the two executable files, you'll see:

```
48,49c48,49
< 000002f0: 474E5500 5CEE13AF 3549A15A E34A9A55  GNU.\...5I.Z.J.U
< 00000300: FD49EC5E 7D1F91EA 01000000 01000000  .I.^}...........
---
> 000002f0: 474E5500 0A2669D1 5FF23AE5 36F7496C  GNU..&i._.:.6.Il
> 00000300: 1E0AA570 51D29111 01000000 01000000  ...pQ...........
276c276
< 00001130: FC010000 008B45FC 89C6BF10 204000B8  ......E..... @..
---
> 00001130: FC020000 008B45FC 89C6BF10 204000B8  ......E..... @..
```

The first diff is the hex for the build id.

The second is the *data*. It is the difference between `NUMBER_1` being 1 and then 2

---

I guess I'd say: *Don't worry, be happy ...*

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know. I was unaware of the readelf utility.